# CasperJS HTTP Authentication

Tags: testing, phantomjs, casperjs

cannot deal with simply HTTP authentication. Here's my code:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1366, height: 667};
casper.start('https://example.com/a/dashboard');
casper.setHttpAuth('username', 'password');

casper.then(function() {
    this.test.assertUrlMatch(/^https:\/\/example.com\/a\/dashboard$/);
});

casper.run(function() {this.test.renderResults(true);});
```

---

And error that I see in console:

```
casperjs mytest.js
FAIL Current url matches the provided pattern
#    type: assertUrlMatch
#    subject: false
#    currentUrl: "https://example.com/login"
#    pattern: "/^https:\\/\\/example.com\\/a\\/dashboard$/"
FAIL 1 tests executed in 2.428s, 0 passed, 1 failed.
```

---

Q: Why my current Url does't match with pattern?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you need to call `casper.setHttpAuth()` before you load the page.

It also looks like you forgot to call `casper.exit()` at the end of `casper.run()`.

```js
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1366, height: 667};

casper.start();
casper.setHttpAuth('here_i_type_username', 'here_password');

casper.thenOpen('https://mysite.com/a/dashboard', function() {
    this.test.assertUrlMatch(/^https:\/\/mysite.com\/a\/dashboard$/);
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.test.renderResults(true);
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: Anyway... Something goes wrong.   
    CasperError: Casper is not started, can't execute`setHttpAuth()`
    /home/test:358 in checkStarted
    /home/test:1390 in setHttpAuth